# PyInstaller: multiprocessing ведёт себя странно

Tags: python, pyinstaller, multiprocessing

Код:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def test():
    print("b")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("a")
    p = Process(target=test)
    p.start()
```

Когда я запускаю скрипт через python, всё работает правильно: программа пишет a, затем b.
Но когда я компилирую его через pyinstaller (вот так: `python -m PyInstaller --onefile why.py`), то программа пишет всё время букву a.

Как это исправить?

Python: 3.10.5

PyInstaller: 5.1

ОС: Windows 10 x64

Comment: у меня ваш код при запуске из IDLE пишет букву `a` один раз после чего завершает выполнение

Comment: По поводу PyInstaller и multiprocessing  есть информация в доках PyInstaller-ра. В кратце он работает не так как ожидается.

Comment: Это вроде не нужно когда собираете через PyInstaller if __name__ == "__main__":

Answer (score 0):

Тут уже ответили на это: **[ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944558/pyinstaller-built-windows-exe-fails-with-multiprocessing)**

Вкратце: Если вы планируете использовать `--onedir`, все, что вам нужно будет добавить, — это вызов специального метода:

**P.s (Весь код взят из ссылки сверху)**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # On Windows calling this function is necessary.
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
```

Если вы планируете использовать --onefile, то необходимо добавить код:

```
import multiprocessing.forking
import os
import sys

class _Popen(multiprocessing.forking.Popen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
            # We have to set original _MEIPASS2 value from sys._MEIPASS
            # to get --onefile mode working.
            os.putenv('_MEIPASS2', sys._MEIPASS)
        try:
            super(_Popen, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        finally:
            if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
                # On some platforms (e.g. AIX) 'os.unsetenv()' is not
                # available. In those cases we cannot delete the variable
                # but only set it to the empty string. The bootloader
                # can handle this case.
                if hasattr(os, 'unsetenv'):
                    os.unsetenv('_MEIPASS2')
                else:
                    os.putenv('_MEIPASS2', '')

class Process(multiprocessing.Process):
    _Popen = _Popen

# ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # On Windows calling this function is necessary.
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    # Use your new Process class instead of multiprocessing.Process
```